# Generalized Siegel Weil formula

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, siegel-modular-forms

I am studying the following Poincare-like series,

\begin{equation}
F_k(\tau,\bar{\tau})=\sum_{\gamma\in\Gamma_{\infty}\backslash\Gamma}\sqrt{\text{Im}\gamma\tau}(q_{\gamma}\bar{q}_{\gamma})^k,
\end{equation}
where $\Gamma=SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, $\Gamma_{\infty}$ generates $\tau\rightarrow\tau+1$ and $q=e^{2\pi\mathrm{i}\tau}$. Can this function be written as the weighted average of some other function? I am trying to find a Siegel Weil like formula for this function, so that I can write it as,
\begin{equation}
F_k(\tau,\bar{\tau})=\int \mathrm{d}\mu G_k(\mu,\tau,\bar{\tau}).
\end{equation}
Is there such a (non-trivial) $G_k$?

Comment: Probably there are some typos in your question: the defn of $\Gamma$? $SL(2,\mathbb C)$? Anyway, would a spectral expansion be what you'd want? It would have a "continuous" as well as a "discrete" part. Would you tighten up the question's notation, and clarify? :)

Comment: @paul garrett, yes it should be $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, I don't know how I missed that, and yes a spectral decomposition should work.

Comment: Ah, ok, as I suspected. But/and, still, I'd let $\Gamma=SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ (not a coset space) and sum over $\gamma\in\Gamma_\infty\backslash\Gamma$. Then people will understand better in terms of contemporary notational styles. :)

Comment: Okay, I made the changes.